# Reordering Excel Table Without Interop Objects

Tags: c#, excel, export, export-to-excel

I am writing a program in C# that is required to reorder a sheet by one of the columns.  At the moment I am unable to use Office Interop objects to control the file, so I have been reading it in using Excel Data Reader (http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) in order to read in the files, as my output is always in csv, tsv, or a SQL table.  Any ideas as to how I would be able to save the DataTable as excel or if a command exists to reorder it without Interop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to save a datatable to Excel, without using Interop, by means of a web-grid.
I suppose you're talking about an application, so you have to make a reference to the `System.Web` library.

The code:

```
// Create the DataGrid and perform the databinding
var myDataGrid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
myDataGrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
myDataGrid.DataSource = myDataTable;
myDataGrid.DataBind();

string myFile = "put the name here with full path.xls"
var myFileStream = new FileStream( myFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite );

// Render the DataGrid control to a file
using ( var myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter( myFileStream ) )
{
    using (var myHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(myStreamWriter ))
    {
        myDataGrid .RenderControl( myHtmlTextWriter );
    }
}
```